# Connecting Tally OBDC to python using pyodbc module (windows 10)

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, tally

I am trying to access a tally database on my localhost through python to integrate the data for a personal project. But I am confused about how to connecting tally OBDC to python through pyodbc module.

Comment: https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/tally-odbc-python-linux.rst

Comment: Is the tally obdc driver of cdata free?

Comment: I have no idea. I provided the link mainly for the instructions, not to recommend a particular driver. (I assumed that you had one already.)

Answer (score 0):

I create a **c# library( [Tally Connector](https://github.com/Accounting-Companion/TallyConnector) )** to connect with Tally easily

- Using Tally Connector you can connect with Tally without any odbc driver so it is independent of os architecture(32bit or 64bit)
- You can use this library in any .NET platform

We can also use this library in python using pythonnet

**If you want connect to Tally using Tally connector in Python refer [this guide](https://blog.saivineeth.com/en/TallyConnector/Python-Tally-Integration_Getting-Started/)**